# React hock useEvent TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

There is this code, it works on js

but not on ts

```
import { useCallback, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react';

type callbackType = (...args: any[]) => any;

export const useEvent = <TF extends callbackType>(callback: TF): TF => {
  const functionRef = useRef<TF>(callback);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    functionRef.current = callback;
  });

  return useCallback((...args) => {
    const functionCall = functionRef.current;
    return functionCall(...args);
  }, []);
};
```

error here: return useCallback(***(...args) => {***

TS2345: Argument of type '(...args: any[]) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TF'.
'(...args: any[]) => any' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TF', but 'TF' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'callbackType'.

how to solve this problem without resorting to `//@ts-ignore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {useRef, useLayoutEffect, useCallback} from 'react';

type callbackType = (...args: Array<any>) => any;

interface useEventOverload {
  <TF extends callbackType>(callback: TF): TF;
  <TF extends callbackType>(callback: TF): any;
}

export const useEvent: useEventOverload = (callback) => {
  const callbackRef = useRef(callback);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current = callback;
  });

  return useCallback((...args: any) => {
    return callbackRef.current(...args);
  }, []);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't really explain why, but the issues seems to be with the `...args: any[]` from `callbackType`, which could not be "respected".

So I modified a bit callbackType to take two generics (one for the parameters and one for the result), and I added the constraint that the input should extend `any[]` (so it works well with the rest parameters), which seems to fix the issues.

```js
import { useCallback, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";

type callbackType<A extends any[], R> = (...args: A) => R;

export const useEvent = <A extends any[], R>(
  callback: callbackType<A, R>
): callbackType<A, R> => {
  const functionRef = useRef(callback);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    functionRef.current = callback;
  });

  return useCallback((...args) => {
    const functionCall = functionRef.current;
    return functionCall(...args);
  }, []);
};

function Component() {
  const cb = useEvent((x: number, y: string) => {
    return "Hello world";
  });

  cb(1, "test");

  return null;
}
```